# looking for method in python standard library

Tags: python, python-2.7, standard-library

In my python standard library(Python `2.7`), I am looking for specific methods within the modules.

For e.g. if i open `re.py`, i can see that there are specific methods like `findall`,`search` etc.
The same is evident when i do `dir(re)`. I can clearly see the above methods.

Similarly,when i do `dir(os)`, there exists a method called `system`, which i usually call using `os.system(cmd_name)`.

But when i look for this method under `os.py`, it does not exist. Am i doing something wrong? Please guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function is not defined in the `os` module, so you won't find the definition in `os.py`. It's imported into `os` from another module; which module that is will depend on your operating system. You can check:

```
>>> os.system.__module__
'nt'
```

Here, you can see that since I'm on Windows, `os.system` comes from the `nt` module.

---

You'll probably find that `os.system.__module__` is either `'nt'` or `'posix'`, representing either the `nt` or `posix` module. The question then is, where are those modules defined? There's no `nt.py` or `posix.py`.

It turns out these modules are implemented in C, in [`Modules/posixmodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c). Yes, the `nt` module is `posixmodule.c`, and so is the `posix` module. It's weird.

Comment: How do i access nt module ? I want to see the code for def system

Comment: @fsociety: Answer expanded.

Comment: is there a way to look at the posixmodule.c ? Pardon my ignorance

Comment: @fsociety: If you look again, you'll see that I've provided a link!

Comment: @fsociety: You can't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130656/discussion-between-fsociety-and-user2357112).